# Sum of two normal products is Laplace?

Tags: normal-distribution, proof, quadratic-form, laplace-distribution

It is apparently the case that if $X_i \sim N(0,1)$, then

$X_1 X_2 + X_3 X_4 \sim \mathrm{Laplace(0,1)}$

I've seen papers on arbitrary quadratic forms, which always results in horrible non-central chi-squared expressions.

The above simple relationship does not seem at all obvious to me, so (if it is true!) does anyone have a simple proof of the above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An elementary sequence of steps using well-known relationships among distributions and a simple algebraic [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) provide an elementary and intuitive demonstration.

I have found this polarization identity generally useful for reasoning about, and computing with, products of random variables, because it reduces them to linear combinations of squares.  It is a bit like working with matrices by diagonalizing them first.  (There's more than a superficial connection here.)

---

**A Laplace distribution** is a [difference of two Exponentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Relation_to_the_exponential_distribution) (which intuitively makes some sense, because an Exponential is a "half-Laplace" distribution).  (The link demonstrates this by manipulating characteristic functions, but the relation can be proven using an elementary integration following from the definition of a difference as a convolution.)

**An Exponential distribution** (which itself is a $\Gamma(1)$ distribution) is also a (scaled version of a) [$\chi^2(2)$ distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)  The scale factor is $1/2$.  This can easily be seen by comparing the PDFs of the two distributions.

**$\chi^2$ distributions** are obtained naturally as sums of squares of iid Normal distributions (having zero means).  The degrees of freedom, $2$, count the number of Normal distributions in the sum.

**The algebraic relation**

$$X_1X_2 + X_3X_4 = \left[\left(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{X_3+X_4}{2}\right)^2\right] - \left[\left(\frac{X_1-X_2}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{X_3-X_4}{2}\right)^2\right]$$

exhibits $X_1X_2 + X_3X_4$ in terms of squares of four distributions, each of which is a linear combination of standard Normals.  It is easy to check that all four linear combinations are linearly independent (and each follows a Normal$(0,\sqrt{1/2})$ distribution).  Thus the first two terms, which sum the squares of two identically distributed Normal distributions of mean zero, form a *scaled* $\chi^2(2)$ distribution (and its scale factor of $\sqrt{1/2}\ ^2=1/2$ is exactly what is needed to make it an Exponential distribution) and the second two terms independently have an Exponential distribution, too, for the same reason.

Therefore $X_1X_2+X_3X_4$, being the difference of two independent Exponential distributions, has a (standard) Laplace distribution.

Comment: That is absolutely delightful!

Comment: I just noticed that another answer, based on moment generating functions, appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51717/919: see the paragraph in the middle beginning "incidentally" (another name for the Laplace distribution is "bi-exponential").  That thread concerns the MGF of a generalization of the present question.

Comment: Nice derivation, but how do you know that the difference of two independent exponential distributed variables has a Laplacian distribution?

Comment: @Hello Please follow the link: it goes to a Wikipedia article that includes a brief demonstration.

Answer (score 13):

$X\sim \mathrm{Laplace}(0,1)$ has characteristic function
$$
\phi_X(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2}
$$
which is the square of the characteristic function of a product standard normal (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74013/characteristic-function-of-product-of-normal-random-variables). The claim follows by the fact that sums of independent random variables relate to products of characteristic functions.